# save file path in variable with javascript, without fakepath?

Tags: javascript, file, path, save

Before I have commented that I am using a script in javascript as the following one, to guard the route of a file in a variable, there is any way of doing it, although not using javascript, in order that the mistake does not go out for me of fakepath? I do not want to save the file, only its path.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function CopyMe(oFileInput, sTargetID) {
    document.getElementById(sTargetID).value = oFileInput.value;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <input type="file" onchange="CopyMe(this, 'txtFileName');" />
</div>
<div>
    You chose: <input id="txtFileName" type="text" readonly="readonly" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

thaks for your help

Comment: i know IE8 and below, depending on security settings, would give you the entire path. i doubt any browers today would do so.

Comment: Is there any way to get the path using html?

Comment: you can have the user enter it in a `text` input. that probably isnt what you want though.

Comment: well, that would be the last option. With php or java,inside html code , it would be done?

Comment: there might be a way of a java, flash, silverlight, etc. plugin, but probably not php. i dont think php would ever need to know the path of a file being sent to it.

Comment: ok,  thak you for the help :)